# What happens to energy when wave interfer? And is it possible that a mechanical and electromagnetic wave interfer

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have been wondering if the energy changes when two waves interfer constructivly and destructively and if different types waves are able to interfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given their fundamental differences(mechanical waves need a medium to interact in, while their electromagnetic counterparts do not), it is not common for mechanical and electromagnetic waves to directly interfere with each other in the traditional sense of wave interference(ie constructive and destructive interference). Mechanical waves interact primarily with other mechanical waves in the same medium, and electromagnetic waves interact primarily with other electromagnetic waves. That being said, I know two such cases where this could occur.

Transduction: In some cases, mechanical waves (e.g., sound waves) can be converted into electrical signals, which can then interact with electromagnetic waves (e.g., radio waves) when transmitted through electronic devices like microphones and speakers.

Scattering and Absorption: Electromagnetic waves, such as light, can interact with materials and scatter or be absorbed by them. When this happens, the absorbed energy can cause mechanical vibrations or heat generation in the material, which can be considered a form of indirect interaction between the two types of waves.

Comment: Thanks for responding and i would appreciate it if you could answer the first part of my question about what happens to the energy of the waves when they interfer